# ¿Porqué mi aplicación de Windows 64 mapea bibliotecas kernel32, gdi32, win32u, etc.?

Tags: c, windows

Estuve explorando e intentando aprender un poco sobre la arquitectura y los detalles de bajo nivel de Windows x64. Para ver un poco cómo se organiza el espacio de memoria de los procesos compilé una aplicación básica y la cargué en el debugger. Curiosamente, en el espacio de memoria están mapeadas las bibliotecas kernel32.dll, gdi32.dll, user32.dll, gdi32full.dll y win32u.dll. No tengo motivo para asumir que porque tienen 32 en el nombre están de alguna forma atadas a 32 bits, aunque me resultó llamativo. ¿Alguien sabe si es solo una cuestión de nomenclatura o si realmente hay algo más profundo?

Gracias.

Comment: es por compatibilidad ( mucha app con nombres hardcodeados ) en un sistema windows 64 bits las librerías 64bits están en /windows/system32 y las librerías 32 bits están en /windows/syswow64 mismo nombre distinto biteness

Comment: Ahh, entiendo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Siempre se llamaran kernel32.dll, etc., incluso en Windows de 64 bits. Esto es por las mismas razones de compatibilidad que system32 contiene binarios de 64 bits, mientras que syswow64 contiene binarios de 32 bits.

Windows de 64 bits proporciona dicho entorno "listo para usar" y es compatible con aplicaciones de 32 bits que utilizan el subsistema "Windows en Windows 64", abreviado a WOW64, que se ejecuta en modo de usuario y asigna las llamadas de 32 bits al sistema operativo kernel en una llamada equivalente de 64 bits. Normalmente, esto es casi invisible para el programa que hace la llamada. Windows proporciona un conjunto de DLL de 64 bits en% windir% \ system32 y un conjunto equivalente de DLL de 32 bits en% windir% \ syswow64. De hecho, la mayor parte de las imágenes binarias en este directorio son idénticas a los mismos archivos en el directorio system32 en una instalación de Windows de 32 bits. (Me parece un desafortunado problema de nomenclatura que las DLL de 64 bits esten en system32 y las de 32 bits en syswow64, pero ahí están)

Por ejemplo:

En las versiones de Windows de 64 bits, uno de los "kernel32.dll" s contiene un código de 64 bits, pero aún se llama kernel32.dll. Esto es algo engañoso.

Espero que los siguientes enlaces te ayuden:

- http://www.howzatt.demon.co.uk/articles/DebuggingInWin64.html
- http://www.viva64.com/en/l/0002/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaron_margosis/using-ntfs-junctions-to-fix-application-compatibility-issues-on-64-bit-editions-of-windows

Fuente: Tomado el ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364741/does-64-bit-windows-use-kernel64

Comment: Graicas @eyllanesc !!